# Select and copy a block of cells

Tags: vba

I use the following VBA in order to select a block of cells and then copy it. However, the results show that Excel ***ONLY*** copy the ***last*** cell in that block. Why? How to fix? Thanks.

```
Sheets(1).Select
Range("B8").Activate
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Update:

I figured out another way to fix it (might not be very clever):

```
Sheets(1).Select
Range("B8").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.Name = "LastCell"
Range("B8", "LastCell").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: If your block of cells is separate from any other cells you can use: `Range("B8").CurrentRegion.Copy`

Comment: @LaTeXFan If my answer help you please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim nr_rows As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")

With ws
   nr_rows = ws.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
   ws.Range("B8:B" & nr_rows).Copy
End With
```

If you want with `selection`

```
Sheets("1").Select
Range("B8").Activate
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Or in one row:

```
Sheets("1").Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column)).Select
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation, please? Such as where I went wrong and why yours works, etc.

Comment: Because you don't define the range you want property.  I edited the post with the correct select.

Comment: Your code select only first cell and after that, the last cell, not making a range because you don't define a range in your query.